# Disable checkout button in cart

Tags: magento-1.8, checkout, quote

I have added an error in the **`sales_quote_save_before`** event, if the quantity of items is more than 500.

```
> Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addError(Mage::helper('checkout')->__('The maximum order qty is %d', 500));
```

The error appears in the cart, but still I can go further to the checkout and place the order. How can I disable the **Proceed to Checkout** button?

Answer (score 5):

You can disable the checkout button by adding the following to the quote object (in the event your use for your observer `sales_quote_save_before`):

```
$quote->setHasError(true);
$quote->addErrorInfo(
    'error',
    'checkout',
    null,
    Mage::helper('checkout')->__('The maximum order qty is %d', 500),
    null
);
```

This will display the error message in the cart and remove the buttons. This solution is also used by the catalog_inventory module when a product qty is over the available qty.

Answer (score 0):

you could create an if statement that checks the qty is below the required value. The 'Proceed to Checkout' link comes from this file.

```
  app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/link.phtml
```

This question has a lot of details on checking individual product quantities in the cart. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8296719/magento-get-the-quantity-in-cart-for-a-given-product

Answer (score 0):

If you want something without fiddling with your core code then i think its better to observe the proceed to checkout event ( if you are using onepagechekout that will be `<controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_index>` ) and then checking if the quantity constraints are not met  then you can set the error there and use the below code to reload to cart itself

```
$url = Mage::getUrl('checkout/cart'); Mage::app()->getResponse()
->setRedirect($url) ->sendResponse();
```

Comment: ok i think that's the best solution anymore. i checked how magento handles it with the minimum amount value you can configure in the default magento settings. That's more or less static code in the controller actions. If i would like to do it like that, i would have to rewrite a lot of controllers and blocks. Thank you!

Comment: for completeness sake: It's <controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_index>

Comment: Edited. I had to implement the same thing and i used `<controller_action_predispatch_onepagecheckout_index>` should be because i have installed a onepagecheckout plugin. I guess!