# click proceed to checkout and page reload and set Disable checkout button in cart

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, event-observer

I have use observer for "controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_index" and in set but not disable proceed checkout button...anything missing?

```
$quote->setHasError(true);
                // Mage::app()->getStore()->setConfig('checkout/options/onepage_checkout_enabled',1);
                Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addError('Remove Products.');
                Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('checkout/cart'));
```

Comment: Please explain your question properly,

Comment: Check this but not working for me..http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/32891/disable-checkout-button-in-cart#comment44471_32899